# Width of search bar expands as you type?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to find a way to do this but maybe it's not possible...

Is there a way you can get the search bar to expand to the width of the content of the text inside it? So it gets wider as you type. Then design wise I'm thinking of center aligning it, and position absolute a submit button to the right, I've done a mock up of what I'm trying to explain...

[image]

I'm guessing it's either really simple and obvious or really overly complicated!

Any thoughts or help would be great, thanks!

Ps, I'm good for help with button etc just showed that for context...

Comment: https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ummmmmm...thanks! Two people replied, it helped, and I was able to create what I needed. I have to design and build projects on my own for a large company, I don't always have the luxury of time.

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but something you can get started with.

Uses an extra `<span>` placed offscreen to get the width from.

```
<span id="offscreen"></span>
#offscreen {
    position:absolute;
    top:-999em;
    left:-999em
}
```

JS

```
var $test_span = $('#offscreen')

var $input = $('input').keydown(function () {
    var val = $input.val();
    $test_span.text(val);
    $input.width($test_span.width() + 20);// add 20 for some padding
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bp91p7op/)**</kbd>